# Identify a tropical foliage plant with variegated glossy elliptic leaves

Tags: identification, houseplants

[image]

Need help with the name of the plant so that I can take proper help. It's a tropical plant

Comment: Does  it have a bulbous stem - only the leaves are visible in the pic

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Got it at last - it is Ctenanthe lubbersii, also known as Ctenanthe pilosa, though originally its name was Calathea ctenanthe lubbersii - I think this variety is probably Golden Mosaic. Common name is Brazilian Snow Plant, but there are probably other common names. They do not appreciate direct sunlight, but need bright daylight, otherwise the variegation fades to plain green. They do not like to dry out, but equally don't want to be waterlogged - aim to keep the soil in the pot damp but not soggy. Water with tepid water, preferably soft or distilled water. They need even temperatures and always over 60 degrees F, with no draughts. In warmer, more tropical regions, they can be used outdoors in shade/dappled shade, but more info here on growing as a houseplant https://www.houseplant411.com/houseplant/ctenanthe-plant-how-to-grow-care

Comment: How tall does this plant grow?

Comment: 18 inches as a houseplant  - it says that in the link.